# How to fix - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException - in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, cloudsim

I wanted to create Cloudsim simulation in Eclipse IDE. I have make sure there is no significant error that should gives problem to the program. But when I run the program, this issue appear.

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Host.vmCreate(Host.java:221)
at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.VmAllocationPolicySimple.allocateHostForVm(VmAllocationPolicySimple.java:92)
at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Datacenter.processVmCreate(Datacenter.java:443)
at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Datacenter.processEvent(Datacenter.java:216)
at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.core.SimEntity.run(SimEntity.java:426)
at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.core.CloudSim.runClockTick(CloudSim.java:523)
at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.core.CloudSim.run(CloudSim.java:887)
at org.cloudbus.cloudsim.core.CloudSim.startSimulation(CloudSim.java:188)
at cloudsimProject.cloudsimSimulation.main(cloudsimSimulation.java:93)
```

---

I don't know which null should I change to fix this issue. This is the code.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Cloudlet;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.CloudletSchedulerTimeShared;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Datacenter;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.DatacenterBroker;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.DatacenterCharacteristics;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Host;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Log;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Pe;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Storage;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.UtilizationModelFull;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.Vm;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.VmAllocationPolicySimple;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.VmSchedulerSpaceShared;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.core.CloudSim;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.provisioners.BwProvisionerSimple;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.provisioners.PeProvisionerSimple;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.provisioners.RamProvisioner;
    import org.cloudbus.cloudsim.provisioners.RamProvisionerSimple;

    public class cloudsimSimulation {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int numUser=1;
        Calendar cal;
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        boolean traceFlag=false;
        CloudSim.init(numUser, cal, traceFlag);

        Datacenter dc = CreateDataCenter();

        DatacenterBroker dcb = null;

        try
        {
            dcb = new DatacenterBroker("DatacenterBroker1");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<Cloudlet> cloudletList = new ArrayList<Cloudlet>();

        long cloudLetLength = 40000;
        int pesNumber = 1;
        long cloudletFileSize = 300;
        long cloudletOutputSize = 400;
        UtilizationModelFull fullUtilize = new UtilizationModelFull();

        for(int cloudletId=0;cloudletId<40;cloudletId++)
        {
            Cloudlet newCloudlet = new Cloudlet(cloudletId, cloudLetLength, pesNumber, cloudletFileSize, cloudletOutputSize, 
                fullUtilize,fullUtilize,fullUtilize);
            newCloudlet.setUserId(dcb.getId());
            cloudletList.add(newCloudlet);
        }
        List<Vm> vmList = new ArrayList<Vm>();

        long diskSize = 20000;
        int ram = 2000;
        int mips = 1000;
        int bandwidth = 1000;
        int vCPU = 1;
        String VMM = "XEN";

        for(int vmId=0;vmId<40;vmId++)
        {
            Vm virtualMachine = new Vm(vmId, dcb.getId(), mips, vCPU, ram, bandwidth, diskSize, VMM, 
                    new CloudletSchedulerTimeShared());
            vmList.add(virtualMachine);
        }

        dcb.submitCloudletList(cloudletList);
        dcb.submitVmList(vmList);

        CloudSim.startSimulation();

        List<Cloudlet> finalCloudletExecutionResults = dcb.getCloudletReceivedList();

        CloudSim.stopSimulation();

        int cloudletNo=0;
        for(Cloudlet c : finalCloudletExecutionResults)
        {
            Log.printLine("Result of cloudlet No " + cloudletNo);
            Log.printLine("**********************");
            Log.printLine("ID:"+c.getCloudletId()+ "Vm:"+c.getVmId()+ "status:"+c.getStatus()+ ",Execution Time:"+c.getActualCPUTime()+ ",Start:"+c.getExecStartTime()+ ",finish:"+c.getFinishTime() );
            Log.printLine("**********************");
            cloudletNo++;
        }
    }

    private static Datacenter CreateDataCenter()
    {
        List<Pe> peList = new ArrayList<Pe>();

        PeProvisionerSimple pProvisioner = new PeProvisionerSimple(1000);

        Pe core1 = new Pe(0, pProvisioner);
        peList.add(core1);
        Pe core2 = new Pe(1, pProvisioner);
        peList.add(core2);
        Pe core3 = new Pe(2, pProvisioner);
        peList.add(core3);
        Pe core4 = new Pe(3, pProvisioner);
        peList.add(core4);

        List<Host> hostlist = new ArrayList<Host>();

        int ram = 8000;
        int bw = 8000;
        long storage = 100000;
        Host host1 = new Host(0, RamProvisionerSimple(ram), new BwProvisionerSimple(bw), storage, peList, 
                new VmSchedulerSpaceShared(peList));
        hostlist.add(host1);
        Host host2 = new Host(1, RamProvisionerSimple(ram), new BwProvisionerSimple(bw), storage, peList, 
                new VmSchedulerSpaceShared(peList));
        hostlist.add(host2);
        Host host3 = new Host(2, RamProvisionerSimple(ram), new BwProvisionerSimple(bw), storage, peList, 
                new VmSchedulerSpaceShared(peList));
        hostlist.add(host3);
        Host host4 = new Host(3, RamProvisionerSimple(ram), new BwProvisionerSimple(bw), storage, peList, 
                new VmSchedulerSpaceShared(peList));
        hostlist.add(host4);

        String architecture="x86";
        String os = "Linux";
        String vmm="XEN";
        double timeZone = 5.0;
        double ComputecostPerSec = 3.0;
        double costPerMem=1.0;
        double costPerStorage=0.05;
        double costPerBW=0.10;

        DatacenterCharacteristics dcCharacteristics= 
                new DatacenterCharacteristics(architecture, os, vmm, hostlist, timeZone, ComputecostPerSec, costPerMem, costPerStorage, costPerBW);

        LinkedList<Storage> SANstroage = new LinkedList<Storage>();

        Datacenter dc=null;

        try
        {
            dc = new Datacenter("Datacenter1", dcCharacteristics, new VmAllocationPolicySimple(hostlist), SANstroage, 1);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return dc;
    }

    private static RamProvisioner RamProvisionerSimple(int ram) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

---

I hope you could help me fix this issue.

Comment: Debugging you application might also help find the issue.

Comment: @DorianGray I would not call it a duplicate of that one, since in this case, the exception results from calling a static zero-argument method.  The usual steps for debugging a NullPointerException are unlikely to help.

Comment: No, they are very likely to help, by just looking at the stack trace.

Comment: NullpointerException is not in the class you posted. It's in `Host.java:221`. Post that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The method `private static RamProvisioner RamProvisionerSimple(int ram)` returns null and is used several times when initializing your Hosts

Comment: I see... How should I change it?